# Redaction of regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to create a regex for replacing this kind of string :

(x bla bla bla)

Im looking for replace (x bla bla bla) by (x) then add new text

Here my jsfiddle : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5f96y13z/1/)

here my code :

```
var StartingLetter = 'x';
var NewText = 'Dadidu'
var regexTest = new RegExp('('+StartingLetter +')',"g");
            
$('.select_list option').text(function(i, oldText) {
    //BlankText transform (x bla bla bla) by (x) ==> Doesnt work
    var BlankText= oldText.replace(/\('+StartingLetter +'*?\)/, '('+StartingLetter +')')

    //Then i replace with the new sentence (x) by (x Dadidu) 
    return oldText.replace(regexTest, StartingLetter +' '+ NewText);              
});
```

Comment: Your current regex is trying to match the string "+StartingLetter +".  If you're trying to use a variable don't put it in quotes.

Comment: If you're trying to replace everything after the letter x, all you need is `oldText.replace(/x.*/, 'Dadidu')`

Comment: `oldText.replace(/\('+StartingLetter +'*?\)/` - you can not use string concatenation in this place (because you are not in a string context to begin with.) If you want to create a regular expression build from "variable" parts, then you _need_ to use the RegExp constructor for that.

Comment: All the jQuery related code is totally unnecessary for describing the core Problem. The OP should provide real example strings (without `x` and without `bla bla`) together with the expected result. This is easier to grasp on and less likely to be misunderstood than the so far describing words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to revamp the code as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var StartingLetter = 'x';
var NewText = 'Dadidu'
            
$('.select_list option').text(function(i, oldText) {
    return oldText.replace(new RegExp(String.raw`\((${StartingLetter})[^()]*\)`,'g'), `($1 ${NewText})`)
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://altair-html.tzdthemes.com/assets/js/common.min.js"></script>
<select class="select_list">
<option>Hello option A (x blabla bla)</option>
<option>Hello option B (x dididdidi)</option>
</select>
```

Here,

- `` new RegExp(String.raw`\((${StartingLetter})[^()]*\)`,'g') `` declares a regex dynamically, `String.raw` help avoid doubling backslashes, `g` allows matching all non-overlapping occurrences in the string. Note the added `[^()]*` part, it matches zero or more chars other than round parentheses, and `${StartingLetter}` is wrapped with capturing parentheses
- `($1 ${NewText})` is the replacement pattern, `$1` stands for the captured Group 1 value and `${NewText}` is the word you want to append to the `(x` part.

Comment: thx for the explanation ;)